# When citing a paper on arXiv, how important is the category?

Tags: citations, arxiv, bibtex

The arXiv documentation says that we should reference arXiv documents using references of the form:

```
arXiv:YYMM.NNNNv# [category]
```

e.g.:

```
arXiv:0706.1234v1 [math.FA]
```

However, most papers that I am aware of do not bother to include the category.  i.e. they have references of the form:

```
arXiv:YYMM.NNNNv#
```

Furthermore, I can't find a BibTeX bibliography style which automatically includes the arXiv category (taken from the `primaryClass` in BibLaTeX).

Also, the arXiv documentation page "[Preparing TeX/LaTeX Papers for Submission](https://web.archive.org/web/20170706232807/https://arxiv.org/corr/latexhelp)" suggests that arXiv documents should be referenced using just the arXiv ID, e.g. `arXiv:0705.1234`  (i.e. without the category).

My question is: is it OK to produce a list of references *without* any arXiv categories (i.e. just `arXiv:0705.1234`)?

Answer (score 7):

The arXiv documentation page on "[Understanding the arXiv identifier](http://arxiv.org/help/arxiv_identifier)" contains the following sentence, which directly answers my question:

"*Note that the identifier no longer contains any classification information and thus reclassification after an article is announced is possible.*"